# How to Implement Calendar into Widget

Tags: java, android, calendar, widget

So I have an app that shows a calendar countdown, works perfectly. I want to add an app widget, I went ahead a made NewAppWidget.Java file in my project, I have no clue how to implement the code from my app into the code for the widget. I want to be able to show how many 'Days' left until the event, in my widget! Hope that makes sense.

Here's my code!

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView tv_countdown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown_text_view);


    Calendar start_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 06);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    end_calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);// 10 = November, month start at 0 = January

    long start_millis = start_calendar.getTimeInMillis(); //get the start time in milliseconds
    long end_millis = end_calendar.getTimeInMillis(); //get the end time in milliseconds
    long total_millis = (end_millis - start_millis); //total time in milliseconds


    //1000 = 1 second interval
    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(total_millis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

            long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);

            tv_countdown.setText(days + " Days" + "\n" + hours + " Hours" + "\n" + minutes + " Minutes" + "\n" + seconds + " Seconds" ); //You can compute the millisUntilFinished on hours/minutes/seconds

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv_countdown.setText("Finished");

        }
    };
    cdt.start();


}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)?

Comment: I don't understand how to implement it into the widget though?